# save google map polygon to postgreSQL database

Tags: google-maps, postgresql, polygon, postgis

I develop a web-based application where a user will create a polygon on a map and the database 
will return points of interest.

The problem is that the postgreSQL saves the polygon in a different way than google map polygon.

So how I can save the user polygon to postgis?

I already use google maps v3  api and geojson

Answer (score 3):

Some code would be useful. In the absence of that here's a best guess generic answer: In general terms you will need to work out how to map (convert) each format to the other. Then you can convert to the format suitable for the database before you save and convert from database format to google maps format when you retrieve. I imagine each polygon is a set of latitude/longitude pairs in both formats so it shouldn't be too difficult.

Alternatively, since you're using JSON, you could just save the JSON to a text field in the database (or to a JSON field in the upcoming 9.2 release of PostgreSQL):

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-json.html

However if you would like to perform geographical queries in the database that would obviously limit your options.

Answer (score 2):

In my js file  i create a shape which is polygon

```
shape = new google.maps.Polygon({
 Editable:true,
 strokeColor: 'FF0000',
 strokeOpacity: 0.8,
 strokeWeight: 1,
 fillColor: 'FF0000',
 fillOpacity: 0.4
});
```

Then I create the function addPoint

```
function addPoint(e) {
 shape.setMap(map);
 vertices= shape.getPath();
 vertices.push(e.latLng);
 polygon.push(e.latLng);
}
```

I pass the addPoint function to map object

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
google.maps.event.addListener(map,'click',addPoint);
```

In my html I have the button with id=polygon. I convert the coordinates in postgres format (long,lat)

```
$("#polygon").click(function(e){
 a=JSON.stringify(polygon);
 var c=JSON.parse(a);
 console.info(c);
 vertices.forEach(function(xy, i) {
  x.push(xy.lng()+" "+xy.lat());
 });
 shape.setMap(map);
```

The variable which contains the polygon is the array which I called it x 
the I have an ajax call to pass polygon array x to my model

```
$.ajax({
 url: 'myurl',
 type: 'post',
 data: {'polygon':x},
 datatype: 'json',
 success: function(data) {
 console.info(data)
 }
});
```

In my model (Codeigniter) I convert the polygon (lat,long)  to postgres polygon (long,lat)

```
public function getPolygon($polygon){
 header('Content-type: application/json');
 $upolygon="";

$length=count($polygon);
for ($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){
 $upolygon.=$polygon[$i].' ,';
}
$upolygon.=$polygon[0];
$query = "some query with the formated polygon";
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
 {
  $data[]= array("some data");
 }
 echo json_encode($data);
}
```