# How to clear shapes after the map is redrawn in Google maps?

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps-api-3, overlay, shapes

I want to clear google map overlay shapes after they are redrawn using JSON string but its not clearing after the map is redrawn using Json string.

1. When i draw shapes and click save raw(IO.IN(shapes,false)) and after that if i click clear button, it clear all shapes.
2. After i saved the shapes if i click on  restore(IO.OUT(array,map)) button, all shapes are restored and if i want to clear all shapes at that moment and again click clear button it does not clear shapes why??
   or in other words i want to clear map after restoring shapes but its not clearing map why ??
   Can anyone help. Thanks in advance.

My Google map code is given as follows:

```
function initialize()
{   
    var goo             = google.maps,
        map_in          = new goo.Map(document.getElementById('map_in'), 
                                      { zoom: 12, 
                                        center: new goo.LatLng(32.344, 51.048)
                                      }),

        shapes          = [],
        selected_shape  = null,
        drawman         = new goo.drawing.DrawingManager({map:map_in}),
        byId            = function(s){return document.getElementById(s)},
        clearSelection  = function(){
                            if(selected_shape){
                              selected_shape.set((selected_shape.type
                                                  ===
                                                  google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER
                                                 )?'draggable':'editable',false);
                              selected_shape = null;
                            }
                          },
        setSelection    = function(shape){
                            clearSelection();
                            selected_shape=shape;

                              selected_shape.set((selected_shape.type
                                                  ===
                                                  google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER
                                                 )?'draggable':'editable',true);

                          },
        clearShapes     = function(){
                            for(var i=0;i<shapes.length;++i){
                              shapes[i].setMap(null);
                            }
                            shapes=[];
                          };

    goo.event.addListener(drawman, 'overlaycomplete', function(e) {
        var shape   = e.overlay;
        shape.type  = e.type;
        goo.event.addListener(shape, 'click', function() {
          setSelection(this);
        });
        setSelection(shape);
        shapes.push(shape);
      });

    goo.event.addListener(map_in, 'click',clearSelection);
    goo.event.addDomListener(byId('clear_shapes'), 'click', clearShapes);
     goo.event.addDomListener(byId('clear'), 'click', function() {
                   // clearShapes();
                    alert("clear or not");

                    this.shapes = IO.OUT(JSON.parse(byId('data').value), map_in);
if(this.shapes){
        for(var i=0;i<this.shapes.length;++i){
              this.shapes[i].setMap(null);
        }
}

                });
    goo.event.addDomListener(byId('save_encoded'), 'click', function(){
      var data=IO.IN(shapes,true);byId('data').value=JSON.stringify(data);});
    goo.event.addDomListener(byId('save_raw'), 'click', function(){
      var data=IO.IN(shapes,false);byId('data').value=JSON.stringify(data);});
    goo.event.addDomListener(byId('restore'), 'click', function(){
      if(this.shapes){
        for(var i=0;i<this.shapes.length;++i){
              this.shapes[i].setMap(null);
        }
      }
      this.shapes=IO.OUT(JSON.parse(byId('data').value),map_in);
    });

}


var IO={
  //returns array with storable google.maps.Overlay-definitions
  IN:function(arr,//array with google.maps.Overlays
              encoded//boolean indicating whether pathes should be stored encoded
              ){
      var shapes     = [],
          goo=google.maps,
          shape,tmp;

      for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
      {   
        shape=arr[i];
        tmp={type:this.t_(shape.type),id:shape.id||null};


        switch(tmp.type){
           case 'CIRCLE':
              tmp.radius=shape.getRadius();
              tmp.geometry=this.p_(shape.getCenter());
            break;
           case 'MARKER': 
              tmp.geometry=this.p_(shape.getPosition());   
            break;  
           case 'RECTANGLE': 
              tmp.geometry=this.b_(shape.getBounds()); 
             break;   
           case 'POLYLINE': 
              tmp.geometry=this.l_(shape.getPath(),encoded);
             break;   
           case 'POLYGON': 
              tmp.geometry=this.m_(shape.getPaths(),encoded);

             break;   
       }
       shapes.push(tmp);
    }

    return shapes;
  },
  //returns array with google.maps.Overlays
  OUT:function(arr,//array containg the stored shape-definitions
               map//map where to draw the shapes
               ){
      var shapes     = [],
          goo=google.maps,
          map=map||null,
          shape,tmp;

      for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
      {   
        shape=arr[i];       

        switch(shape.type){
           case 'CIRCLE':
              tmp=new goo.Circle({radius:Number(shape.radius),center:this.pp_.apply(this,shape.geometry)});
            break;
           case 'MARKER': 
              tmp=new goo.Marker({position:this.pp_.apply(this,shape.geometry)});
            break;  
           case 'RECTANGLE': 
              tmp=new goo.Rectangle({bounds:this.bb_.apply(this,shape.geometry)});
             break;   
           case 'POLYLINE': 
              tmp=new goo.Polyline({path:this.ll_(shape.geometry)});
             break;   
           case 'POLYGON': 
              tmp=new goo.Polygon({paths:this.mm_(shape.geometry)});

             break;   
       }
       tmp.setValues({map:map,id:shape.id})
       shapes.push(tmp);
    }
    return shapes;
  },
  l_:function(path,e){
    path=(path.getArray)?path.getArray():path;
    if(e){
      return google.maps.geometry.encoding.encodePath(path);
    }else{
      var r=[];
      for(var i=0;i<path.length;++i){
        r.push(this.p_(path[i]));
      }
      return r;
    }
  },
  ll_:function(path){
    if(typeof path==='string'){
      return google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(path);
    }
    else{
      var r=[];
      for(var i=0;i<path.length;++i){
        r.push(this.pp_.apply(this,path[i]));
      }
      return r;
    }
  },

  m_:function(paths,e){
    var r=[];
    paths=(paths.getArray)?paths.getArray():paths;
    for(var i=0;i<paths.length;++i){
        r.push(this.l_(paths[i],e));
      }
     return r;
  },
  mm_:function(paths){
    var r=[];
    for(var i=0;i<paths.length;++i){
        r.push(this.ll_.call(this,paths[i]));

      }
     return r;
  },
  p_:function(latLng){
    return([latLng.lat(),latLng.lng()]);
  },
  pp_:function(lat,lng){
    return new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
  },
  b_:function(bounds){
    return([this.p_(bounds.getSouthWest()),
            this.p_(bounds.getNorthEast())]);
  },
  bb_:function(sw,ne){
    return new google.maps.LatLngBounds(this.pp_.apply(this,sw),
                                        this.pp_.apply(this,ne));
  },
  t_:function(s){
    var t=['CIRCLE','MARKER','RECTANGLE','POLYLINE','POLYGON'];
    for(var i=0;i<t.length;++i){
       if(s===google.maps.drawing.OverlayType[t[i]]){
         return t[i];
       }
    }
  }

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

HTML code is given as follows:

```
<div class="map" id="map_in"></div>
<div style="text-align:center">
   <input id="clear_shapes" value="clear shapes"    type="button"  />
  <input id="save_encoded" value="save encoded(IO.IN(shapes,true))"    type="button" />
  <input id="save_raw"     value="save raw(IO.IN(shapes,false))"        type="button" />
  <input id="data"         value=""                style="width:100%" readonly/>
  <input id="restore"      value="restore(IO.OUT(array,map))"         type="button" />
                      <input  id="clear"     name="clear"  value="clear" type="button" />

</div>
```

Where and how can I clear the shapes created on map. All shapes are saved in the var all_shapes = []; array. I'm going to use JSP.

Comment: The posted code has javascript errors.  Or maybe I just don't know how you expect it to be used...

Comment: what errors?? kindly can u tell me?

Comment: i want to use it when i draw shape and press the clear button, it clear all shapes and when i press restore button , all shapes are restored and again press clear button. it does not clear why??

Comment: i have also updated my question .please help me ..if u r not clear then tell me i will clear it more as i can.

Comment: after resoring the shapes i want to clear map but its not clearing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [original implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19614805/how-to-save-a-google-maps-overlay-shape-in-the-database/19620629#19620629) uses 2 different maps, the issue in your implementation is located in the restore-function:

```
goo.event.addDomListener(byId('restore'), 'click', function(){
  if(this.shapes){
    for(var i=0;i<this.shapes.length;++i){
          this.shapes[i].setMap(null);
    }
  }
  this.shapes=IO.OUT(JSON.parse(byId('data').value),map_in);
});
```

`this` here refers to the clicked button, so `this.shapes` will not affect the `shapes`-array declared in `initialize`, but you must modify this array.

Use this instead:

```
goo.event.addDomListener(byId('restore'), 'click', function(){
  while(shapes.length){
    //hides the shape and removes it from the shapes-array
    shapes.pop.setMap(null);
  }
  shapes=IO.OUT(JSON.parse(byId('data').value),map_in);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should remove all the shapes in the all_shapes array from the map:

```
for (var i=0; i<all_shapes.length; i++) {
   all_shapes.setMap(null);
}
```

Comment: `all_shapes[i].setMap(null);` ?

Comment: i am already doing it in this way but its not working see my clear button code: if(this.shapes){
        for(var i=0;i<this.shapes.length;++i){
              this.shapes[i].setMap(null);
        }