# custom google map with drawing shapes and store in database

Tags: asp.net, database, google-maps-api-3

I want to create a custom google map like [this](http://bl.ocks.org/knownasilya/89a32e572989f0aff1f8) and want to draw and store diffrent shapes like polyline, polygone,line, point, etc with custom data(info window,id etc) and style(color, strockcolor etc) to database. but i dont know how .is there any one to help me?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

By checking the [Google Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays), there is an object called overlays that can add objects to the map to designate points, lines, areas, or collections of objects. Overlays are tied to latitude/longitude coordinates, so they move when you drag or zoom the map.

The Google Maps JavaScript API has several types of overlays that you can add programmatically:

- Single locations on the map are displayed using **markers**.
- An **info window** is a special kind of overlay for displaying content (usually text or images) within a popup balloon at a given location on a map
- Lines on the map are displayed using **polylines** representing an ordered sequence of locations and Areas of arbitrary shape on the map are displayed using **polygons**. See [Shape](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#polygons) for more information.
- You can also define **circles** and **rectangles** on the map
- If you want to place an image on a map, you can use a **ground overlay**

For storing the data on a database, I think this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3) and [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19614805/how-to-save-a-google-maps-overlay-shape-in-the-database) can help you for doing that.